# What happens when I reset my iPod?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

I heard that if I reset my iPod, I will lose everything.

Is there anything I can do to not lose all my apps, information, etcetera?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will lose all your settings. That is the whole purpose of [reseting a device](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2110#). If instead, you just want to [restart your device](http://www.apple.com/support/ipodtouch/assistant/ipodtouch/#section_1), you hold the Sleep/Wake button and the Home button at the same time for at least 10 seconds. For clarification: **Reseting** will erase your data, **restarting** will not erase your data.

The easiest way to backup an iPod Touch these days is to use iCloud backup. Apple has all the directions on [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766). Basically all you do is go to **Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Backup Now**.

Then once it's done with the backup (it may take several hours), you will be able to use it to restore your device. Restoring all the data is simple as well. All you do is choose the **Restore from iCloud Backup** option when it asks you to set up the new device.

Make sure you keep your username and password for iCloud in a safe place, because you will need it again after you restore your device.

Comment: "several hours" !? Didn't you meant "minutes" ?

Comment: @Rabskatran: It could be minutes or hours, depending on if you have performed a backup before, how much data needs to be transfered, and your network connection, among other things.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an iOS device you can back it up using iTunes, if not try an app like [Senuti](http://www.fadingred.com/senuti/) to rip everything back to the computer from the iPod.

Comment: Seconding senuti. That is is you dont already have everything in your iTunes Library.

Answer (score 0):

By resetting, if you just held down the home and sleep button for 10 seconds, you won't lose your stuff. 
When I restored mine, I lost all my music but that's about it.